# Is Elasticsearch more performant over a SQL Server DB or a NoSql Db?

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, search, nosql

I work on a project which allows recruiters to search for candidates by going through their CV texts. The CV text is stored as a string and could be many numbers of lines.
The search currently uses a stored procedure on a SQL-Server and dynamic SQL.

We are thinking of making this a more performant application and Elastic-Search has been nominated as a good search technology.

One question is however, what would be the best persistence storage for our project, since a CV seems to be a non-structured piece of data and we already store the CV files in a file storage? Would the choice of the persistence storage affect our search performance?